# does a linear proof exist for "Sum of four cubes problem"?

Tags: number-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_four_cubes_problem) there is a proof for case 18x+1 and that is
$$ 18x+1 = (2x+14)^3+(-2x-23)^3+(-3x-26)^3+(3x+30)^3 .$$
Can you prove that a similar equation does not exist for $ a_1x+4 $ in such a way that $a_1≠0$ ?

In other words , can you prove that this equation
$$ a_1x+a_2=(A_1x+B_1)^3+(A_2x+B_2)^3+(A_3x+B_3)^3+(A_4x+B_4)^3$$
(for any x) has no solutions for $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4, B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$
in such a way that $ a_1≠0 $ and $a_2=18k+4$ ($a_2$ is congruent to 4 modulo 18)?